# Cast errors when changing the data type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I did a scaffold of an existing database with EF Core 3.1 (problem also exists in EF Core 2.2.6)
Provider: Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore

After scaffolding I have for example properties like that.

```
[Column("CODE", TypeName = "NUMBER(4)")]
public byte Code { get; set; }
```

This is very unfortunate. I can not read one single line because a Number(4) will never fit into a byte.
So I changed all bytes manually to short.
With the result that I get cast errors like:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Byte'.
```

I have no idea what's going on here and why it cares about internal database datatypes. The only chance I have is to remove all TypeNames.
The only problem then is that I have to specify the type in a migration every time I touch the column.

Is there a better way or at least an explanation what it going on here?

Comment: can you change byte to Int16?

Comment: It probably cares because the data type in the database (`smallint`?) corresponds to `short` (aka `Int16`) in C#. As implied by the 16, it is a 16-bit number, vs byte which is 8-bit. `byte` is also unsigned. All this means that you can't store a number smaller than 0 or bigger than 255 in it, whereas your database field could contain values between -32,768 and 32767.

Comment: It does not matter if I change the byte to short or Int16. It seems that internally somewhere it is of the opinion that Number(4) has to be a byte and nothing else. What a strange behaviour. Especially because byte is totally wrong in this case.

Comment: It seems that the scaffolding logic assumes that values of datatype `byte` will be stored in Oracle using the `number` datatype. I would expect that `number(3)` would be used, meaning that such field values in Oracle would be able to have three digits. I do not know why and how that fourth digit would be necessary.

Comment: Somehow I can understand the logic of EF. It says: I ensure that you will get the value into the database. So the type in the db has to be bigger than the c# type. Ok. But scaffolding is the exact opposite direction. ef has to ensure that I get the already existing values in the db into c# data types. To have the same logic than with code first makes no sense here.

Comment: I am not familiar with the scaffolding logic. I do not trust scaffolding very much, just for reasons like this issue of yours. So I personally prefer the tedious and explicit coding routes. Are there any (hidden) generated files that still use `byte`/`System.Byte` instead of `short`/`System.Int16`? If *every* usage of `byte` and `System.Byte` is replaced with `short` respectively `System.Int16`, your appliation should not be able to throw those conversion exceptions IMHO.

Comment: I can't see any hidden magic with scaffolding. It just creates the classes and a dbcontext with fluent stuff (but without specifying any types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle is investigating this. Seems to be a bug.
Especially with Number(4)

[EDIT] Oracle won't fix it.